# HAProxy resolve all redirects before delivering to user

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, webserver, haproxy

I have the following setup:

> Apache 2.4 Web Server (:80) <-> HAProxy (:80, :443) <-> Internet

And the following problem:

On some pages I have three redirects before the user gets to the actual page.  For example:

> https: somepage.com/subpage -> (302) http: somepage.com/subpage/ -> (302) https: somepage.com/subpage/ ->(200)

Is there a way that HAProxy resolves all redirects before delivering to the user?

I read somewhere that nginx is capable of that.